# Docker-Compose - unable to change working_directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my Dockerfile I'm setting the working directory using: `WORKDIR /usr/src/app` and then later in the file I need to update it `WORKDIR /usr/src/app/src/front` to run some further build commands.

Now in my docker-compose when I want to run a specific `npm run api`, it has to be done from `/usr/src/app`. As I updated the WORKDIR in the Dockerfile itself, I've been trying to update the working directory using the following in my docker-compose however it doesn't seem to move into that specific directory - I see an error stating it can't find `npm run start` and on looking at its in the directory `/usr/src/app` instead of `/usr/src/app/src/front` as I've specified with `working_dir`

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  front:
    image: myimage
    working_dir: /usr/src/app/src/front
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    command: ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Is it even possible to update the working_dir like I'm trying to?

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM node:12.18-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

# Build the frontend
RUN cd /usr/src/app/src/front \
    && npm install \
    && npm run build

COPY . .
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is [exactly the syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir).  Can you provide a more complete example with a Dockerfile and the error you're getting?

Comment: Please post the output with all error messages. Did you try something like `ls -lah` as command and `/tmp` as workdir just to see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to override `WORKDIR` as well as some other Dockerfile directives (`ENTRYPOINT`, `CMD`) at launch with `docker run` or in `docker-compose.yml`. You've done the overwriting right in the example, so the problem is somewhere else.

Also note that you can just `cd` to temporary change working directory in Dockerfile. For example:

```sh
RUN cd /usr/src/app \
    && npm run build \
    && cd src/front \
    && npm run build
    # and so on
```

When you use `WORKDIR` you set the **default** working directory. It is good to point to where your app's root is but it is quite unusual to use it to build an image.

Comment: Thanks - I think using WORKDIR twice in my Dockerfile was causing some issues. I've updated it to do the above like `RUN cd src/front && npm run build`. Will see if that helps in doing WORKDIR in the docker-compose instead

Comment: @userMod2 As I said, you did overriding well and successfully changed workdir third time with docker-compose. Be there an error - add it to the question along with the Dockerfile if you can afford it.

Comment: @anemtye - I've updated the original post with mre complete code. Thanks

Comment: @userMod2 run this `docker-compose run --entrypoint="" front ash`. This will bring you into container's shell. Try using console commands to start the server manually and investigate the issue.

Comment: On doing that and running `npm run start` it works as expected when I do this locally.
On Azure where I am running this it keeps showing `missing script: start`.

Comment: Infact when starting it shows `docker run -d -p 3883:3000 --name sw_front -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false myrepo.azurecr.io/myimage npm run start`

As I can't see that working diretcory there I wonder if I need to somehow pass it as an env variable

Comment: Infact I wonder if that `working_directory` is even supported by Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#docker-compose-options

Comment: @userMod2 Indeed it isn't mentioned there. You can learn that for sure by slightly changing your compose file: `entrypoint: ""` and `command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "pwd && docker-entrypoint.sh npm run start"]`. The first line in the log will be the working directory path. In any case `WORKDIR` in Dockerfile must work. If there are several - the last one will be used when the container starts.

Comment: Its showing `/usr/src/app` not `/usr/src/app/src/front` as i have in the wordir so I'm guess its not supported! Will think of a workaround for the time being. Tahnks for your help.